# Getting Keys and Values from IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, dictionary, system.reflection

I have a  `IEnumerable < Dictionary < string, object > >`  object.

I want to get the "aaavalue" "bbbvalue" "cccvalue" "dddvalue" in a array.

Sample Data:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> testData = new IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>();

/* Values in testData will be like
   [0] - 
         aaa - aaaValue   (Key, Value)
         bbb - bbbValue
         ccc - cccValue
         ddd - dddValue  
   [1] - 
         aaa - aaaValue   (Key, Value)
         bbb - bbbValue
         ccc - cccValue
         ddd - dddValue  

    and so on */
```

I know it is possible using Reflection or LINQ. But I could not able to make it up.

Please help..

**Answer:**

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> enumerable = testData as List<Dictionary<string, object>> ?? testData .ToList();
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> objects in enumerable)
{
    IEnumerable<object> values = objects.Select(x => x.Value); // To get the values.
    IEnumerable<string> keys = objects.Select(x => x.Key); // To get the keys.
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get values"? What is the expected result?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I want to get the "aaavalue" "bbbvalue" "cccvalue" "dddvalue" in a array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with:

```
IEnumerable<object> values = testData.SelectMany(x => x.Values);
```

Comment: Your code is working. But I want to get all rows. Your code is for only one row.

Comment: What do you mean by "rows" and "one row"?

Comment: The object I have is of type Enumerable. Your code is just giving me the values at testData[0]. I want to get all the values at testData

Comment: @RameshDurai check it with other data  because values of first item are de same of second item!!!

Comment: You should have 8 values at the end.

Comment: @Alessandro Yes I have :) But is it possible to get each row data separately(possibly in a array)instead of whole.

Comment: object[] values = testData.SelectMany(x => x.Values).ToArray(); but it's the same.